# How to write different contents to multiple files

Tags: perl

I would like to write different content in multiple files using Perl.

Specifically, assuming that `$start_no=2` and the number of lines in the input file is `3`, I want to write to the specified file as follows.

```
2 3 4 5 in tmp1.txt

6 7 8 9 in tmp2.txt
...
```

The following code creates the specified output file `tmp1~4.txt`, but does not write anything in it.

None of the values in the input file are used in this code because I have removed the parts that are probably not needed.

```
my $infile=$ARGV[0];
my $start_no=$ARGV[1];

open (my $infh,'<',$infile);

my $i=0;
my $j;
for ($j=1;$j<5;$j++) {
  my $outfile1="tmp1.txt";
  my $outfile2="tmp2.txt";
  my $outfile3="tmp3.txt";
  my $outfile4="tmp4.txt";

  open (my $outfl1,'>',$outfile1);
  open (my $outfl2,'>',$outfile2);
  open (my $outfl3,'>',$outfile3);
  open (my $outfl4,'>',$outfile4);

  while ( my $line= <$infh>) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1) {
      next;#skip label
    }

    my $line_no1 = 2 * ($start_no - 2) + 2;
    my $line_no2 = $line_no1 + 1;

    if ($j == 1) {
      print $outfl1 "$line_no1 \n";
      print $outfl1 "$line_no2  \n";
    }
    elsif ($j == 2) {
      print $outfl2 "$line_no1  \n";
      print $outfl2 " $line_no2 \n";
    }
    elsif ($j == 3) {
      print $outfl3 "$line_no1 \n";
      print $outfl3 "$line_no2  \n";
    }
    else {
      print $outfl4 "$line_no1 \n";
      print $outfl4 " $line_no2  \n";
    }
    $start_no++;
  }
  close ($outfl1);
  close ($outfl2);
  close ($outfl3);
  close ($outfl4);
}
close ($infh);
```

What I tried was to put in print `$outfl1;` before writing to the output file and it would show `GLOB(0x2208c38)`.

Thank you

Comment: I've added some indentation and other whitespace to your code. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing it yourself in future. Whitespace is an important tool in understanding code and if you're asking a group of strangers to read and understand your code, then it's only polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. You reopen your output files each time round your main loop. This will remove any data that was written to the files on previous iterations of the loop. Fix this by moving the code that opens (and closes) these files outside of the loop.
2. You try to read from your input file each time round your main loop. But once the first iteration has read this filehandle to the end, there is no more data to read and subsequent iterations can't read anything more from the file. You could fix this by reopening the file each time, but it's more efficient to use `seek()` to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the filehandle each time.

So my version of your code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile   = $ARGV[0];
my $start_no = $ARGV[1];

open (my $infh, '<', $infile);

my $outfile1 = "tmp1.txt";
my $outfile2 = "tmp2.txt";
my $outfile3 = "tmp3.txt";
my $outfile4 = "tmp4.txt";

# Opne this files outside of the loop
open (my $outfl1, '>', $outfile1);
open (my $outfl2, '>', $outfile2);
open (my $outfl3, '>', $outfile3);
open (my $outfl4, '>', $outfile4);

my $i = 0;
my $j;
for ($j = 1; $j < 5; $j++) {
  # Reset the file pointer each time
  seek $infh, 0, 0;

  while ( my $line= <$infh>) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1) {
      next;#skip label
    }

    my $line_no1 = 2 * ($start_no - 2) + 2;
    my $line_no2 = $line_no1 + 1;

    if ($j == 1) {
      print $outfl1 "$line_no1 \n";
      print $outfl1 "$line_no2  \n";
    }
    elsif ($j == 2) {
      print $outfl2 "$line_no1  \n";
      print $outfl2 " $line_no2 \n";
    }
    elsif ($j == 3) {
      print $outfl3 "$line_no1 \n";
      print $outfl3 "$line_no2  \n";
    }
    else {
      print $outfl4 "$line_no1 \n";
      print $outfl4 " $line_no2  \n";
    }
    $start_no++;
  }
}

close ($outfl1);
close ($outfl2);
close ($outfl3);
close ($outfl4);
close ($infh);
```

This certainly produces data in each of the output files, but I'm not sure whether it's the right data :-)

A couple of other points:

- You might consider putting your four output filehandles into an array.
- `for ($j = 1; $j < 5; $j++)` is probably more readable as `foreach my $j (1 .. 4)`.

Comment: They could even switch the loops and make the whole thing run in one pass

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn't know about the seek function. I fixed my program and it goes well!!